# Getting Wrong Count in JAVA Count Letters Program

Tags: java, count

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code, why am I not getting the correct letter count?

This program reads a text file and count each English letters, A-Z, and a-z, not case sensitive.

Thank you for helping.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {
    private static int a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z;
    public static void print(){
        int[] in = {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z};
        for (int i = 0; i < in.length; i++){
            System.out.println(in[i]);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{

        File file = new File("t.txt");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
        while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scan.nextLine();
            line = line.toLowerCase();
            for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
                switch(line.charAt(i)) {
                    case 'a': a++;break;
                    case 'b': b++;break;
                    case 'c': c++;break;
                    case 'd': d++;break;
                    case 'e': e++;break;
                    case 'f': f++;break;
                    case 'g': g++;break;
                    case 'h': h++;break;
                    case 'i': i++;break;
                    case 'j': j++;break;
                    case 'k': k++;break;
                    case 'l': l++;break;
                    case 'm': m++;break;
                    case 'n': n++;break;
                    case 'o': o++;break;
                    case 'p': p++;break;
                    case 'q': q++;break;
                    case 'r': r++;break;
                    case 's': s++;break;
                    case 't': t++;break;
                    case 'u': u++;break;
                    case 'v': v++;break;
                    case 'w': w++;break;
                    case 'x': x++;break;
                    case 'y': y++;break;
                    case 'z': z++;break;
                }
            }
        }
        print();        
    }
}
```

Comment: @tom: you should definitely have a look at hash tables - it could be implemented much easier :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that when you encounter a `i`, that will increment the variable of the loop, not the one in the array. So you will skip letters.

Change it with :

```
for (int counter = 0; counter < line.length(); counter++) {
                switch(line.charAt(counter)) {
```

Comment: thank you! it was so hard for me to figure out since I take i as granted.

Answer (score 1):

your problem is in the use  the variable i

in your for loop the index counter is i and i is also a variable which you are using to count the occurrences of alphabet 'i'. use this main method, it will work.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{

    File file = new File("t.txt");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
    while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scan.nextLine();
        line = line.toLowerCase();
        for (int index = 0; index < line.length(); index++) {
            switch(line.charAt(index)) {
                case 'a': a++;break;
                case 'b': b++;break;
                case 'c': c++;break;
                case 'd': d++;break;
                case 'e': e++;break;
                case 'f': f++;break;
                case 'g': g++;break;
                case 'h': h++;break;
                case 'i': i++;break;
                case 'j': j++;break;
                case 'k': k++;break;
                case 'l': l++;break;
                case 'm': m++;break;
                case 'n': n++;break;
                case 'o': o++;break;
                case 'p': p++;break;
                case 'q': q++;break;
                case 'r': r++;break;
                case 's': s++;break;
                case 't': t++;break;
                case 'u': u++;break;
                case 'v': v++;break;
                case 'w': w++;break;
                case 'x': x++;break;
                case 'y': y++;break;
                case 'z': z++;break;
            }
        }
    }
    print();        
}
```

also dont forget to close the scanner after you are done.